# Is it possible to create multiple layers in openlayers using one view with contextual filter?

Tags: views, javascript

I have 10~20 content types and need one layer for each content type in openlayers.  Is it possible to create one view with one openlayers data overlay, and use contextual filters to provide the 10~20 layers in need?

To put the question in another way, with the above settings I can create a view with one page or one content pane, and by using a contextual filter, I can provide a list of content page for each content type.  But it seems to me that in order to provide layers, I must create one data overlay for each content type.  The only way I have found to [pass contextual filters to data overlays](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32190/openlayers-using-contextual-filters) seems to do with filtering at another level, rather than to provide more layers.

Comment: I thought you should be able to add a layer with arguments on `admin/structure/openlayers/layers/add` but if you add an OpenLayers Views layer there is no option to pass an argument or contextual filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty understanding your question completely, but I've worked with OpenLayers and Views 3 so I'll try help you out as best I can.

I see what you mean with regards to using a contextual filter on the View which spits out the OpenLayers Data Overlay co-ordinants, as there is no conventional way of passing arguments to the display.

One thing which you could possible try is using the Views API to alter the query that is generated by your OpenLayers Data Overlay view. That way you could just add a WHERE clause to that specific query, filtering by a content type specified in your own code.

I won't go into the specific syntaxes as I don't have time, but look into firstly how to implement the Views API in a custom module. Once the API is being loaded successfully, look into using the following hook to add a custom WHERE clause:

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){}
```

In the hook you'll need to check the view name and display ID to ensure you're targetting the correct view before adding your custom WHERE clause.

I hope this helps, and good luck!

**EDIT: Including the code snippet for the method I mentioned in the comments below**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter()
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

    // this is the name of our View and Display
    if ($view->name == 'my_view' && $view->current_display == 'my_display') {       

        //add the where clause to filter the results based on node content type value
        $query->where['1']['conditions'][] = array(
                    'field' => 'node.type',
                    'value' => 'your_content_type_here',
                    'operator' => '=',
                  );            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Simply put, I want to reuse the data layer, not by cloning but by setting contextual filters, for showing new content types.  But thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try it.

Comment: I also had a situation come up in a project where I needed to change the contextual filters of a view based on what content type was being parsed as an argument. I ended up using the hook above to add the correct WHERE clause to the query depending on the content type :) I also wanted to avoid cloning a million displays and that hook let me acheive that